# Invalid use of group function with insert SQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm doing a simple insert to a MariaDB database,it's just a simple insert, this is the query.

```
Insert into serie (nombre,carpetas,fecha_ingreso) 
values ('asdads',1,'2018-11-28');
```

The table has an autoincremental primary key and the fields i'm trying to insert are just a simple string, a number and a date, and the fields obviously match the fields the table is suppose to receive.

But the query doesn't go through, instead i get this error.

> error code: #1111 Invalid use of group function

I've searched the web for it but nothing comes up related to an insert query, and I honestly just don't see the syntax error in the query.

It may be some obvious thing I'm missing.

### Edit

The table has this trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_serie_inserted` AFTER INSERT ON `serie`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE last_serie_id int;
DECLARE last_caja_id int;

set last_serie_id = MAX(serie.idserie);
set last_caja_id = MAX(caja.idcaja);


INSERT INTO caja_serie (caja_id,serieDoc_id) VALUES 
(last_caja_id,last_serie_id);


END
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only query you are running ? and it is not part of some larger query ? Or maybe some other queries running before this query and causing the error instead ?

Comment: i agree with @MadhurBhaiya i doubt that query causes a `error code: #1111 Invalid use of group function` you didn't even use aggregate functions like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT()`, or `SUM()` in that query

Comment: Not caused by the published code but  you have any triggers on serie?

Comment: Yes, i do have a trigger for that table. But how does that affect a query that's supposed to run after that query is executed

Comment: Since you noticed it i'll specify that that table has a trigger and i'll also add the code for the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set last_serie_id = MAX(serie.idserie);
```

-->

```
SELECT MAX(idserie) INTO last_serie_id FROM serie;
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, things are working fine DB-wise in my project now.